# Fetch data in chunks for kendo datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I'm trying to fetch data in chunks for a kendo datasource that I bind to a dropdownlist. Fetching the data in one shot throws script warning messages in IE 8. I have close to 1600 items in the datasource. So I hope to request data in pages and merge them once all the fetching is complete. I'm not sure about the approach and I so I haven't got any code to share. This is the script warning message I get.

[image]

Comment: What is the script warning message? How many things are you putting in this drop down? From a usability perspective, it might be better to put items in a ListView that supports paging.

Comment: I think the answer from a UI/UX perspective is "don't put 1600 items in a dropdown list" Even if you get all the items into the browser, it isn't going to like having to render 1600 items in the dropdown anyway, even if it was plain HTML. And certainly no user is going to want to scroll through a dropdown with 1600 items in it. Do you really need all of those? Maybe an AutoComplete box with server-side filtering would be more appropriate? Or a ListView with endless scrolling?

Comment: I agree with @CodingWithSpike. If you see that error is not because of transferring getting too long but actually processing the data in the browser. Transferring on chunks and then put all together will not make it any faster and the browser will choke anyway.